# solution to $x=\log(x)+c$, not through numerical method

Tags: proof-verification, fundamental-solution

I have got some equation $x=\log(x)+c$. Is there any particular solution to this(not with numerical methods)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably another case of how you don't have to be very adventurous to describe a non-elementary function. Would put money down that there does not exist an elementary function $f$ for which $f(c) = \log (f(c)) + c$ for all $c$.

Answer (score 4):

$x = - W(-e^{-c})$ where $W$ is any branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$x=\log x+ \log c$$
$$x=\log(xc)$$
$$10^x=xc$$

Comment: can you elaborate more? form here how to get a a particular solution for x?

Comment: Well, to get a particular solution, I believe $you$ need to give more info. Like value of $f(x)$ at an $x$@Arindam

Comment: I think you still cannot have a closed-form solution for that, still get the numerical solution

Comment: yup, numerical solution is possible, but I was wondering whether any mathematical solution is possible.

Comment: Perhaps you could check out the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: @Arindam, numerical methods are very much a part of mathematics. So a solution using numerical methods is a mathematical solution. If the answer had been $x=\arctan (a+\frac{1}{b})$, would you have accepted the answer as "mathematical"?

Comment: @ I understand that I could have narrated the question in different language, I just wanted people to understand, anyway I have edited it